# Should I avoid mentioning my sick relative as my reason for leaving my job?

Tags: job-change

Recently a family member was diagnosed with dementia. I'm happily employed, but I'd like to be closer to be able to spend time with them, so I'm seeking out remote work.

I've been here a year, and it's going well - the team has grown from 4 to 15, and I've moved into a lead developer role. It's sort of hard to explain why I'm leaving without disclosing personal details.

Compounding is that I've been working as a dev for 7 years and had 7 jobs. Most have been contract, but this is FTE. No one's brought it up, but I imagine I might look like a flake.

Suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Any chance that mentioning your relative's disease and your desire to work remotely might help you get a remote position in you current company?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't be too worried about your resume. In this day and age changing jobs often is basically the norm, especially as you've been working on contracts for most of your career.

If you have a good working relationship with your managers, which you might, as the company was very small when you started, then you could try revealing your situation, and asking for some help and guidance.

Perhaps they will be able to create a remote position for you, or at least allow you to work from home a few days out of the week while you find another job. They might even be able to offer some you some leads for a new job, and give you great recommendations.

If you wish to keep a more arm's-reach approach then simply tell them that a personal matter requires that you work from home for the foreseeable future. Just don't expect as much understanding if you don't offer any details.

At the end of the day you may quit at any time, for any reason. I understand your concern regarding your resume, but if you explain to potential employers that you were typically on contract, and now must seek a remote position due to personal reasons then you will most likely not run into any huge issues.

Answer (score 1):

You won't qualify as a job hopper if you make it explicit that your previous jobs were all contract jobs - It's expected that you leave after you've done what you're supposed to do and nobody is paying you to stay or allowing you to stay.

You might consider negotiating several days a week where you can perform remote work - make sure to explain your relative's situation so no one in your management jumps to any conclusion that you are dissatisfied.

I work remotely, and I am lucky. Remote work is still hard to get and you have to have a track record, preferably at the company where you are working, so that they have a degree of confidence that you'll be able to: 1. handle your assignments at home; 2. manage your interactions with the onsite staff.

It's probably best that you talk to your management about the possibility of some percentage of your work being remote - you are a known quantity to your management and you've been in your current job for only a year. You are not a known quantity to your next employer and the fact that you have been an FTE for only a year might work against you.

Answer (score -2):

You have legal rights potentially to care for a disabled family member under the federal Family Medical Leave Act.  The requirements are 1 year of employment, 1250 hours actual work in the last year, 50 employees within 75 miles of your job location, and a "serious medical condition," of a family member, including a parent.

You likely qualify based on your facts, IF you decide to work for a full year before resigning.  You are allowed up to 12 weeks leave to care for your parent, and entitled to the same job on return.  Not all 12 weeks must be taken at the same time.

This info is slightly off your question, but relevant.  Here are two suggestions:  Use your 12 week leave to get a better assessment of whether your physical presence is really needed all the time in the vicinity of your parent.  You might use the FMLA a week at a time for example (with a supporting doctor's note for need) to monitor, visit, and care for your parent.Secondly, if you're a developer, your work could allow you to work "remotely."  That is, seek to step down from your lead position, and negotiate as an alternative to resignation a "home office" arrangement closer to your parent.  Be prepared to make the case you can work remotely without loss of effectiveness. Also, point out this kind of remote work has been done by others successfully (if it has).

As for the specific question, you're obviously uncomfortable with sharing your private family information.  You have no legal duty to say why you're resigning, so don't.  The new normal of job turnover is that neither employer nor employee are showing particular loyalty or expected long term employments.  Sad, yes, but if your industry has high turnover, you may be able to explain the situation in a new application for employment as the truth:  to care for an ill family member.

[www.employee-rights-atty.com](http://www.employee-rights-atty.com)